# How to send Json data to a list of an object to use from a path on the C: drive

Tags: java, json, list, objectmapper

**code for using my json to a path**

```
public static List<MusicPiece> jsonToListObject(String path) throws Exception {
        return new ObjectMapper().readValue(new FileInputStream(path), new TypeReference<List<MusicPiece>>() {});
    }
```

**main to send a sysout of the data in the json sent to the list**

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

```
    List<MusicPiece> articleList = jsonToListObject("c:/data/json/data_song.json");
    for (MusicPiece musicPiece : articleList) {
        System.out.println("title: " + musicPiece.getMusic_title());
        System.out.println("duree : " + musicPiece.getDuree());
        
    }
}
```

**Music Piece class**

```
public class MusicPiece implements Comparator<MusicPiece>{
private String music_title;
private String genre;
private String interprete;
private int duree; 


public MusicPiece(String music_title, String genre, String interprete, int duree) {
    this.music_title = music_title;
    this.genre = genre;
    this.interprete = interprete;
    this.duree = duree;
    
}


public String getMusic_title() {
    return music_title;
}


public void setMusic_title(String music_title) {
    this.music_title = music_title;
}


public String getGenre() {
    return genre;
}


public void setGenre(String genre) {
    this.genre = genre;
}


public String getInterprete() {
    return interprete;
}


public void setInterprete(String interprete) {
    this.interprete = interprete;
}


public int getDuree() {
    return duree;
}


public void setDuree(int duree) {
    this.duree = duree;
}


@Override
public String toString() {
    return "MusicPiece [music_title=" + music_title + ", genre=" + genre + ", interprete=" + interprete + ", duree="+ duree + "]";
}


@Override
public int compare(MusicPiece o1, MusicPiece o2) {
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Json file with the mock data**

`[{"id":1,"title":"Porter","author":"Horton Twydell","liked":false,"duration":3.04}, {"id":2,"title":"American Ash","author":"Kenton Kamall","liked":false,"duration":4.1}, {"id":3,"title":"Dovetail","author":"Juieta Meedendorpe","liked":false,"duration":4.66}]`

I'm getting this error when I use it like shown in the main method

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of com.Entities.MusicPiece(no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)
```

Comment: I want to know how to make the data in the json as a List so I can use it in methods and just call it when I need

Comment: Yeah I tried sending it to a list but the code doesn't work

Comment: ok here is what i'm trying to do 

`public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  
  List<MusicPiece> articleList = jsonToListObject("c:/data/json/data_song.json");
  System.out.println(articleList);
   
  }
 }`

I know i'm missng something but I don't know why its giving me an error

Comment: Use _[Gson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gson)_ instead.

Comment: no but i need to use fasterxml and object mapper to make this work and i want to figure out why its not working

Comment: What’s the problem that you’re having? Please put details in the question, not a comment. If you are getting an exception, copy the entire exception message and stack trace and paste it into the question, formatted as a code block.

Comment: You’ll also need to include the JSON data that you’re trying to parse and the definition of the `MusicPiece` class

Comment: sure let me add it

Comment: ok I added the code for the json and the musicPiece class

Comment: @Reilas Jackson will work perfectly fine. Please give more details than "_use something different_", siting performance or how it'll solve this specific issue any differently

Comment: I'm getting this error when I use it like shown in the main method  `Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of com.Entities.MusicPiece(no Creators, like default constructor, exist): cannot deserialize from Object value (no delegate- or property-based Creator)`

I'm trying to find its meaning

Comment: I'm still lost the answer is nice but I can't figure where to use `@JsonProperty("field name in json")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSON you've shared has no matching fields with your Music class, and therefore cannot be parsed.

If you want fields to be set differently than they exist in the file, you must add `@JsonProperty("field name in json")` annotations to each field.

Also, as the error says, you need to add a default, no arg, constructor to the class

Comment: Thanks for explaining the error but should I add the `@JsonProperty("field name in json")` in the class MusicPiece and also i'm not quite sure I understand where there should be no arguments and a default.

Comment: You can't add that annotation if your JSON records aren't actually Music records. For example, you have no `int id`. And you already have a constructor. Add another one without any arguments, as the error says. It's not "and" it's one thing called a "default, no arg constructor"

Comment: I looked up some stuff and realised the issue the answer I was given was nice I was just missing an empty constructor for the class

Comment: Yes, but in order to properly create your object, your private fields must match keys in the json data. Otherwise, they'll all be null/zero. For example, duree is a double, not an int, and should be renamed duration